# C++: trying to understand some code

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

okay this is going to be a weirdly (and mostly likely badly) worded question, but here goes. So I'm trying to understand some code for a class but I'm having some trouble. I've got:

This prototype:

```
void split_list(Poly& list1, Poly& list2);
```

Where Poly is a typedef that points to a typedef struct

and then I have the actual function:

```
void split_list(Poly* plist1, Poly* plist2){
  Poly l1 = *plist1;
  Poly l2 = *plist1;
  Poly* pp = &l1
  /*code does stuff w/ the l1 and l2 don't think the specifics are relevant to my 
  question*/
  l2 = *pp;
  (*pp) = 0;
  *plist1 = l1;
  *plist2 = l2;
}
```

My question is why do we set l1 & l2 to *plist1 at the start of the function and then set *plist1=l1 and *plist2=l2 at the very end? Because when I do this instead:

```
Poly l1;
Poly l2;
```

I get a segmentation fault, From what I've gathered we're passing in by reference and the parameters need to have values assigned to them within the function. I feel like I'm missing something here, and I would appreciate any kind of explanation

Comment: Your prototype does not match the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all,

or you pass by reference or you pass by pointer. I prefer the first.

Second, I think that what you are trying to accomplish is:
1. You copy plist1 to l1 and plist2 to l2.
2. You change l1 and l2.
3. You copy the new values of l1 and l2 back to plist1 and plist2.

What I dont undersand is why you copy these classes. Maybe there is some condition that, when happens, you must undo all changes. So, as you dont have changed plist1 and plist2 directly, you just skip the last attribution.

Answer (score 0):

The split_list function probably takes an input list and splits it into 2 lists.

```
Poly l1 = *plist1;
Poly l2 = *plist1;
```

Because plist1 is copied to l1 and l2, I would say this is the input list. Since it's copied to both, the sorting algorithm probably works by removing elements from each list based on certain criteria. The reason you get a segmentation error when replacing this with:

```
Poly l1;
Poly l2;
```

is most likely because the Poly struct contains a pointer which doesn't point to anything and is accessed when the list is sorted.

```
*plist1 = l1;
*plist2 = l2;
```

At the end of the function, it assigns the result of splitting the two lists to plist1 and plist2 as its form of output.